# Nets and compactness in topological spaces.

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, compactness, nets

I am reading Kelley’s book on general topology. There are a few statements on nets there (chapter 2), but the characterization of compact sets in the language of nets is not given. How should we prove the following

**Theorem:** A topological space X is compact iff every net has a convergent subnet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose that $x_\alpha$ is a net in $X$ with no convergent subnet. Then $(x_\alpha)$ do not have accumulation point in $X$. For each $x\in X$, let $V_x$ be an open neighbourhood of $x$ that excludes all the part of the net from some term onward. Let $V=\{V_x:\ x\in X\}$ and note that $V$ is an open cover of $X$. Can you prove that it is impossible to find a finite subcover of $X$ in $V$?

On the other hand, let $V$ be a open cover of $X$ such that every finite subcover of $V$ do not cover $X$. Consider the open cover $U$ of $X$ consisting of finite unions of elements of $V$. If $A,B\in U$, we say that $A\leq B$ when $A\subseteq B$. With this relation, $V$ is an directed set. For $A\in V$, let $x_A\in X\setminus A$. Can you show that the net $x_A$ does not have any convergent subnet?

Comment: I suppose you mean for me to prove those claims by contradiction. Can you give me a hint about where the contradictions stem from.

Comment: Where do you got stucked?

Comment: I'm about as far as nowhere.

Answer (score 9):

See Theorem $15.3$ in [this excellent PDF](http://www.math.tamu.edu/~saichu/netsfilters.pdf), *Translating Between Nets and Filters*, by Saitulaa Naranong; it’s well worth reading the whole thing.

Comment: An interesting paper, but I was a bit confused, because they switched $\Psi$ and $\Phi$ in the definition of subnet on page 11.

Comment: @Stefan: I’m not sure what you mean: on that page he consistently uses $\Psi$ for the subnet and $\Phi$ for the original net.

Comment: I mean $\Psi$ is subnet of $\Phi$ iff $\Psi$ is eventually in all the sets in which $\Phi$ is eventually. So in the second line of Definition 10.2 the arrow should point in the other direction.

Comment: @Stefan: No, the definition goes the other way: $\Phi$ is eventually in all of the sets in which $\Psi$ is eventually. The subnet may be in **more** sets eventually.

Comment: Are you sure? I tried Theorem 11.3.(1), and it seems to work only if it's the other way.

Comment: For example, the sequence $(\frac1n)_\mathbb N$ should rather be a subnet of $(n\%2)_\mathbb N$ than the other way.

Comment: @Stefan: No, it works only with the definition as given. The subnet is eventually in at least as many sets, so its associated filter has at least as many sets.

Comment: @Stefan: What do you mean by $(n\%2)_{\Bbb N}$?

Comment: the remainder $n$ mod 2, the sequence alternating between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: If $\Psi$ is eventually in the sets of $\Phi$, then a tail of $\Phi$ contains a tail of $\Psi$ as a subset, hence Filter($\Phi$)$\subseteq$Filter($\Psi$).

Comment: @Stefan: Neither of those is a subnet of the other: the first is eventually in $(-1/2,1/2)$, and the second one isn’t, while the second is eventually in $\{0,1\}$, and the first one isn’t.

Comment: Oops, you're right. Replace the first one by any sequence which is eventually $0$, but maybe differs at the first few terms.

Comment: @Stefan: I don’t understand what you mean by $\Psi$ being eventually in ‘the sets of $\Phi$’. If you mean that $\Phi$ eventually in $A$ implies that $\Psi$ is eventually in $A$, then you have the filter inclusion backwards.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. Doesn't my second to last comment make sense?

Comment: @Stefan: Aaargghh! You’re right: I’m so used to the ideas that I kept reading what it meant instead of what it said. The one-sentence paragraph under Definition $11.1$ is right, and $\Phi$ and $\Psi$ are indeed reversed in the displayed line of Definition $10.2$.

Comment: :-D Yes, everything they write makes sense except that particular line

Comment: @Stefan: So is everything okay now?

Comment: Yes, of course, if both of us agree now, everthing is fine :-)

Comment: @Stefan: Great! *whew* :-)

Comment: The link is broken but http://web.archive.org/web/20130308175220/http://www.math.tamu.edu/%7Esaichu/netsfilters.pdf still works.

Answer (score 0):

If you are studying Kelley, and you want to prove this subnet characterization of compactness, then a hint is Problem 2 J.