# Prove that if $X$ is sequentially compact then given any $\epsilon>0$ there exists a finite covering of $X$ by open $\epsilon$-balls.

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, metric-spaces, proof-explanation, compactness

At the chapter 4-th in the text *General Topology* Stephen Willard give the following definition

[image]

Now the function $\varphi$ in the previoius definition must **not** be necessary **strictly** increasing so that with respect this definition a subsequence $(x_{n_l})_{l\in\omega}$ of a **injective** sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\omega}$ could be costant, that is it is possibile there exists $n\in\omega$ such that
$$
n_l=n
$$
for any $l\in\omega$. However at the chapter 3-th in the text *Topology* James Munkres gives the following definition.

[image]

which requires that a subsequence of an injective sequence must be injective: anyway sometimes Munkres use the symbol $\subset$ to mean $\subseteq$ so that I supposed that here he does a similar thing but obviously I canno be sure.

Now let's prove that if $X$ is sequentially compact then given any $\epsilon>0$ there exists a finite covering of $X$ by open $\epsilon$-balls.

[image]

So I would like to discuss why $(x_n)_{n\in\omega}$ cannot have any convergent subsequence: indeed if $(x_{n_l})_{l\in\omega}$ was a subsequence converging to $x$ then there would exists $l_\epsilon\in\omega$ such that
$$
x_{n_l}\in B\Big(x,\frac\epsilon 2\Big)
$$
for any $l\ge l_\epsilon$ so that in particular for any $l\ge l_\epsilon$ the inequality
$$
\begin{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq:simple1}{d(x_{n_l},x_{n_{l_\epsilon}})\le d(x_{n_l},x)+d(x,x_{n_{l_\epsilon}})<\frac\epsilon 2+\frac\epsilon 2=\epsilon}\end{equation}
$$
holds but $(n_l)_{l\in\omega}$ must be strictly increasing by Munkres definition so that we conclude that $(x_{n_l})_{l\in\omega}$ does not converges. So is true that Munkres definition requires that $(n_l)_{l\in\omega}$ is strectly increasing? Is Munkres definittion usual? is Willard definition unusual? If Munkres definition does not requires injectivity how prove that $(x_{n_l})_{l\in\omega}$ does not converges? So could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can identify sequences $(x_n)$ in $X$ with functions $x : \mathbb N \to X$, the identification given via $x(n) = x_n$. Thus sequences are also nets in the sense of Willard.

A subsequence of $x = (x_n)$ is then nothing else than a sequence of the form $x \circ \iota : \mathbb N \to X$ where $\iota : \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ is strictly increasing (and in particular injective). Writing $\iota(k) = n_k$, we have $n_1 < n_2 < n_3 < \ldots$ and $(x \circ \iota)_k = (x \circ \iota)(k) = x(n_k) = x_{n_k}$.

This definition is in fact the standard one.

Nets generalize sequences, but the definition of a *subnet* differs form that of a subsequence in two aspects:

1. A subnet is allowed to have a different index set than the original net.
2. The "index function" $\varphi : M \to \Lambda$ is required to be increasing (not strictly increasing) and cofinal.

Willard's definition of a subnet is indeed the [standard one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(mathematics)). But let us emphasize:

- A subnet of a sequence $(x_n)$ may no longer be a sequence.
- Even if we consider only $\mathbb N$-indexed subnets of $(x_n)$, there are index functions which are not strictly increasing. This means that $\mathbb N$-indexed subnets are again sequences, but not necessarily subsequences of $(x_n)$. But of course each strictly increasing $\iota : \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ is increasing and cofinal, thus the set of subsequences of $(x_n)$ is a proper subset of the set of $\mathbb N$-indexed subnets of $(x_n)$.

The sequence $(x_n)$ constructed by Munkres has the property $d(x_j,x_i) \ge \epsilon$ for all $j, i$ such that $j > i$. Thus no subsequence $x \circ \iota$ of $x = (x_n)$ can be a Cauchy sequence (simply because $\iota(j) > \iota(i)$ for $j > i$) and thus no subsequence converges. His statement that $(x_n)$ cannot have a convergent subsequence because no ball of radius $\epsilon/2$ contains at most one $x_n$ is correct (as you proved in your question), but it is actually unnecessary to mention it.

In your answer you correctly show that $(x_n)$ cannot even have a convergent *$\mathbb N$-indexed subnet*. This is in fact a more general result than  that for the *subsequence case*.

Actually we can prove the following theorem valid for all sequences $(x_n)$ in an arbitrary topological space $X$:

- If $x = (x_n)$ has a convergent subsequence if and only if it has a convergent $\mathbb N$-indexed subnet.

The "only if" part is trivial. For the "if" part let $x \circ \varphi$ be convergent $\mathbb N$-indexed subnet (with limit $\xi$). Here $\varphi : \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ is an increasing and cofinal function. By cofinality the image $A = \varphi(\mathbb N)$ is an infinite subset of $\mathbb N$, thus there is a strictly increasing $\iota : \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ such that $\iota(\mathbb N) = A$. We claim that the subsequence $x \circ \iota$ converges to $\xi$.

Since $x \circ \varphi$ converges to $\xi$, each open neighborhood $U$ of $\xi$ in $X$ admits $N$ such that $(x \circ \varphi)(n) \in U$ for $n > N$. Choose $K$ such that $\iota(K) = \varphi(N)$. For each $k > K$ we have $\iota(k) = \varphi(n)$ for some $n$. But $\varphi(n) = \iota(k) > \iota(K) = \varphi(N)$ which implies that $n > N$ since $\varphi$ is increasing. This shows that $(x \circ \iota)(k) = (x \circ \varphi)(n) \in U$ for $k >K$.

Comment: First of all, I thank you for your expansive answer: thanks really. Anyway, I have only one last question: your last theorem guarantees actually that we can define sequential compactness using Willard's definitions, right? Indeed, you supposed that $X$ is a metric space but it seems to me that completely analogous argumentations show that the theorem holds for any general topological space, right?

Comment: Additionally, as I am sure you know, the last image I pasted is an important step of a theorem where is proved that for metric spaces sequential compactness and compactness are equivalent so that when you claim: «In your answer you correctly show that $(x_n)$ cannot even have a convergent subnet indexed by $\Bbb N$. This is in fact a more general result than that for the subsequence case» then I infer that I proved the theorem in agreement with Willard's definition.

Comment: *Postscript*
I think that in 2 you want wrote **is required** and not **is not required**, right?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro You are right in all your points; I made an update. In particular you may work with Munkres' and with Willard's definition, both produce the same result. For compactness of arbitrary topological spaces have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/324842.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro You are right in all your points; I made an update. In particular you may work with Munkres' and with Willard's definition, both produce the same result. If you want, you could speak about subsequences in the sense of Munkres and in the sense of Willard. For compactness of arbitrary topological spaces have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/324842.

Comment: Okay, question upvoted and approved. Thanks very much for your assistance: you really was very kind with me, thanks really. See you soon. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

First of all we observe that if $\iota$ is cofinal map of $\omega$ to $\omega$ then for any $n\in\omega$ there exists $m(n)$ such that
$$
\iota(n)<\iota(n)+1\le\iota\big(m(n)\big)
$$
so that now there exists $l\in\omega$ such that
$$
n_{l_\epsilon}< n_l
$$
and in particular by increase we can suppose that $l>l_\epsilon$ but in this case it would be
$$
d(x_{n_l},x_{n_{l_\epsilon}})\ge\epsilon
$$
which surely inconsistent with $(1)$.